# Access home network machine via hosted subdomain

Tags: subdomain, port-forwarding, ddns

I would like to be able to use a subdomain of my externally hosted website to access a particular port of a machine on my home network. For example, say my domain is `example.com`, I would like to be able to use `homebox.example.com` to talk to port 1234 on a machine on my home network called `homebox`.

Currently, my best solution is to create a forwarding page on my externally hosted website that forwards to a ddns page (using eg duckdns, though I still have to investigate which is the best solution to use) which then passes it to a particular port of my router, which I'm happy configuring to forward to the internal machine (I'm not fussy about specifying the port number: I'm happy to use `homebox.example.com:1234` or whatever works). But that solution seems like one step too many, and I feel like the forward shouldn't be necessary. I'm also not even sure it would work, since this won't be web traffic. Is there a simpler, more robust solution?

I'm very much a n00b at this kind of stuff, so all suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to add DNS entries for your hosted domain a CNAME record pointing to the Dynamic DNS provider domain for your `homebox` should work.

Comment: While trying to get this to work, I discovered my ISP provides static IP as standard, so no need for dyndns at all! All working perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to read! With static IP's the required entry type is a A (IPv4) or AAAA (IPv6) record which directly contains the required destination IP address.